# ASP.NET MVC 4 views debugging

Tags: asp.net-mvc, debugging

I want to insert a breakpoint in a view to see result in a variable; how I can I do that? This is my view where I want to insert a breakpoint to view result:

```
@{
  if (TempData["showModalDialog"] != "true")
     {
       var test= TempData["showModalDialog"];
      }
}
```

Here I want to show data of test.

Comment: just insert the breakpoint like it is inserted normally, and see if it hits.

Comment: no it's not working.

Comment: Raja g! where are you putting `breakpoint`?. If you are putting `breakpoint` at line `var test  = TempData["showModalDialog"]` then if above condition does not meet then this won't hit.

Comment: Dear it is not allowing me insert break point at any point of above given code

Answer (score 0):

The optimizer will get rid of any unused variables. The easiest way is to just use it, and apply the breakpoint there.

```
@{
    if (TempData["showModalDialog"] != "true")
    {
        var test= TempData["showModalDialog"];
        Debug.WriteLine(test);// <-- Breakpoint here
    }
}
```